# Como resuelvo el "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

En mi blog presento todos los articulos en el inicio con un substr de lo que dice el post, luego tengo un boton de leer mas para ver el articulo en otra vista y ahí es donde viene mi error. Me muestra el siguiente error "**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::findBySlug()**"

Mi ruta es la siguiente

```
Route::get('article/{slug}',[
    'uses' => 'FrontController@article',
    'as'   => 'article'
]);
```

Mi **FrontController@article**

```
<?php

namespace Blog\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Blog\Http\Requests;
use Blog\Articulo;
use Blog\User;
use Blog\Categoria;
use Blog\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class FrontController extends Controller{
    public function article($slug){

        $articul = Articulo::findBySlug($slug);
        return view('articulo',compact('articul'));
    }

}
```

Mi view **articulo**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Ultimas Noticias</h1>
                <article>
                    <h2>{{$articul->titulo}}</h2>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{ $articul->categoria->categoria }}
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{ $articul->user->name }}
                        </div><!--fin del col-md-6-->

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{ $articul->created_at }}
                        </div><!--fin del col-md-6-->

                    </div><!--fin del row dentro de col-md-8-->
                    <br>
                    <img src="img/{{$articul->path }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    <br>
                    <p>{{ $articul->contenido }}</p>
                </article>
        </div> <!--fin del col-md-8-->
```

Cuando muestro mis articulos a través del index si se ve bien, pero cuando intento ver un articulo en especial me suelta ese error.

Modelo **Articulo**

```
<?php

namespace Blog;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class Articulo extends Model{

    use Sluggable;

    /**
    * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function sluggable(){
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'titulo'
            ]
        ];
    }
     protected $table = 'articulos';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['titulo', 'contenido','slug','path','etiqueta','user_id','categoria_id'];

    public function setPathAttribute($path){
        if(! empty($path)){
            $name = Carbon::now()->second.$path->getClientOriginalName();
            $this->attributes['path'] = $name;
            \Storage::disk('local')->put($name, \File::get($path));
        }
    }



    public function categoria(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Blog\Categoria');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Blog\User');
    }

    public function scopeTitulo($query, $titulo){//Funcion para hacer una busqueda 
        if(trim($titulo) != ''){ //Funcion trim para eliminar los espacios
            $query->where(\DB::raw("titulo"),"LIKE","%$titulo%");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando sluggable?

Comment: Si, y cuando creo un articulo el titulo pasa al sluggable directamente. Lo instale como dice la documentación.

Comment: Agrega el código del Modelo Articulo, por favor.

Comment: Listo... Ya edite.

Comment: Asumo que el slug sí lo está generando y almacenando en la base de datos?

Comment: Si, exactamente. Me toma el titulo y los espacios los cambia a '-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En las versiones más recientes de Sluggable estos métodos forman parte de los helpers (de Sluggable) y tienes que incluirlos por aparte en tu modelo:

```
<?php

namespace Blog;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableScopeHelpers;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Articulo extends Model{

    use Sluggable, SluggableScopeHelpers;

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Me da el siguiente error al entrar a la pagina principal de mi blog "Trait 'Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableScopeHelpers' not found"

Comment: Estás usando la versión más reciente? aquí está la info respectiva: https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable/blob/master/SCOPE-HELPERS.md yo lo tengo en varios proyectos funcionando sin problema.

Comment: Al parecer tenía la 4.0, ya actualice y funciono.